# Sorting hashmap based on keys

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following hashmap in java:

> {B046=0.0, A061=3.0, A071=0.0, B085=0.0, B075=3.0, B076=9.0, B086=3.0, B095=0.0, B096=0.0, A052=0.0, B066=0.0, B056=9.0, B065=0.0, B055=9.0}

How should I go about sorting the hashmap such that the Alphabet, followed by the numerical figures are taken into account?

The resulting hashmap should look like this:

> {A052=0.0,A061=3.0,A071=0.0,B046=0.0,B055=9.0,B056=9.0,B065=0.0,B066=0.0,B075=3.0,B076=9.0,B085=0.0,B086=3.0,B095=0.0,B096=0.0}

Appreciate the help!

Comment: hashmap is for lookup. It hashes things. It doesn't maintain order.

Comment: @HasanKhan ..who even asked that?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Use sorted `TreeMap`:

```
Map<String, Float> map = new TreeMap<>(yourMap);
```

It will automatically put entries sorted by keys. I think natural `String` ordering will be fine in your case.

Note that `HashMap` due to lookup optimizations does not preserve order.

Comment: Hi @Tomasz Nurkiewicz How can I get the reverse order?

Comment: Can i apply my own comparator

Comment: Great Solution ! There is one prob with 2 digit nos , the sorting becomes 1, 10, 11,12,2,3,4,5 . Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @RachitaNanda, You could try storing the digits with Integer than string.

Answer (score 28):

Use a TreeMap with a custom comparator.

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>
    {
        public int compare(String o1,String o2)
        {
            // Your logic for comparing the key strings
        }
    }

TreeMap<String, Float> tm = new TreeMap<String , Float>(new MyComparator());
```

As you add new elements, they will be automatically sorted.

In your case, it might not even be necessary to implement a comparator because String ordering might be sufficient. But if you want to implement special cases, like lower case alphas appear before upper case, or treat the numbers a certain way, use the comparator.

Answer (score 11):

`TreeMap` is your best bet for these kind of sorting (Natural). `TreeMap` naturally sorts according to the keys.

`HashMap` does not preserve insertion order nor does it sort the map. `LinkedHashMap` keeps the insertion order but doesn't sort the map automatically. Only `TreeMap` in the `Map` interface sorts the map according to natural order (Numerals first, upper-case alphabet second, lower-case alphabet last).

Answer (score 6):

**Use TreeMap (Constructor):**

```
Map<String, Float> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(yourMap);
```

**Use TreeMap (PutAll method):**

```
Map<String, Float> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>();
sortedMap.putAll(yourMap);
```

**Implementation of Map interface:**

1. **TreeMap** - Automatically sort the keys in ascending order while inserting.
2. **HashMap** - Order of insertion **won't** be maintained.
3. **LinkedHashMap** - Order of insertion will be maintained.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), although having a map "look like that" is a bit nebulous--you could also just sort the keys based on your criteria and iterate over the map, retrieving each object.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a `TreeMap`. It implements the `SortedMap` interface, and thus automatically sorts the keys it contains. Your keys can just be sorted alphabetically to get the desired result, so you don't even need to provide a comparator.

HashMaps are never sorted. The only thing you coulkd do with a HashMap is get all the keys, and store them in a sorted set or in a List and sort the List.

Answer (score 3):

Using the **TreeMap** you can sort the Map.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();        
Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(map);
//show hashmap after the sort
for (String str : treeMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TreeMap` which will store values in sorted form.

```
Map <String, String> map = new TreeMap <String, String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

TreeMap will automatically sort in ascending order. If you want to sort in descending order, use the following code:

Copy the below code within your class and outside of the main execute method:

```
static class DescOrder implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {      
        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
    }
```

Then in your logic:

```
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(new DescOrder());
map.put("A", "test1");
map.put("C", "test3");
map.put("E", "test5");
map.put("B", "test2");
map.put("D", "test4");
```