# Inbuilt short method to get array of keys of Hashmap sorted by their values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, hashmap

Many questions have been asked in StackOverflow regarding sorting the Hashmap by key or value. Most of them are posted over many years. For example,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047090/how-to-sort-hashmap-keys/9047176). I am searching for any **onliner method** for sorting the Hashmap keys by their values and get the array of the sorted keys. In iOS, following line of code yields the same:

```
NSArray* sortedKeys = [myDictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]};
```

Here, if the `NSDictionary` myDictionary contains the following objects:

```
{
 S: 1;
 A: 5;
 N: 8;
 T: 2;
 O: 0;
}
```

Then the `sortedKeys` contains the following objects:

```
(N, A, T, S, O)
```

Is such method available in the latest Java? Shall I follow the lengthy solutions? A lengthy solution given [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-sort-hashmap-in-java-by-keys-and-values/) yields a sorted Hashmap (keys sorted by their respective values). Will the order of the sorted keys still persists if I extract the keys of this sorted Hashmap using `keySet()`? 
Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22132422/829571

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using streams, you can write:

```
List<String> keys = map.entrySet().stream()
                      .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue())
                      .map(Entry::getKey)
                      .collect(toList());
```

It's a bit longer than your iOS example but not that bad.

To get the list in reverse order, you can use a reverse order comparator:

```
.sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Entry.comparingByValue()))
```

Comment: you need to reverse it though since OP wants descending order. also technically they wanted an Array not a List

Comment: @PatrickParker they might want an array, but they should use a List in Java.